# md5.h causes my pam module to fail. c programming

Tags: c, linux, hash, md5, pam

I have written a pam module in c and the following code, causes my pam to spit this out.

sudo: pam_authenticate: Module is unknown

I am trying to get the md5 hash value of a string.

```
char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}
```

it works if I comment it out like so

```
char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    /*unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;*/
}
```

I comment out the code and I get this..

```
DEBUG: 08217239
Authentication Code: 08217239
[sudo] password for richardw:
```

Despite the fact of why am I trying to get md5 hash while using pam is trivial, I am working on something and for some reason pam doesn't like. anyone know a work around?

Comment: How do you link the md5 functions into your module?

Comment: #include <openssl/md5.h> /?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely you created a shared object, that lacks symbols. When linking a shared library the linker will not complain about unresolved symbols, because those may be legitimately absent. When loading a library the remaining symbols are resolved using the symbols already loaded. If there still are symbols missing, loading of the shared library is aborted. This is a plausible cause for the error you are seeing from PAM.

An `#include` directive tells the compiler what types specific symbols have, but does not tell it where it finds the corresponding objects. In addition to telling the compiler that those functions do exist, you need to tell the linker where to find them. If you are using gcc, you are likely missing something like `-lssl` on your linker invocation.

Comment: `pkg-config openssl --libs` is what you want.